# Selecting value from NavDropDown Item in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, dropdown, react-bootstrap, use-state

I want to set the value of the symbol and display it within `<h1>` from the react NavDropDown. Following is the code,

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Navbar, Container, Nav, NavDropdown, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';


const PieceNotation = () => {

const [pieceValue,setPieceValue] = useState('King');

function handleChange(event) {

    setPieceValue(event.target.value);

    let symbol='K';

        if(pieceValue === 'Queen'){
            symbol='Q';
        } else if(pieceValue === 'Rook') {
            symbol='R';
        } else if(pieceValue === 'Bihsop') {
            symbol='B';
        } else if(pieceValue === 'Knight') {
            symbol='N';
        } else if(pieceValue === 'Pawn') {
            symbol='a';
        }
    //return symbol;
}

return (
    <>
    <div >
        <Navbar variant="dark" bg="dark" expand="lg">
            <Container fluid>
                <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Piece-Notation</Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="navbar-dark-example" />
                <Navbar.Collapse id="navbar-dark-example">
                <Nav>
                    <NavDropdown
                    id="nav-dropdown-dark-example"
                    title="Dropdown"
                    menuVariant="dark"
                    >
                        <NavDropdown.Item onSelect={handleChange}>King</NavDropdown.Item>
                        <NavDropdown.Item onSelect={handleChange}>Queen</NavDropdown.Item>
                        <NavDropdown.Item onSelect={handleChange}>Rook</NavDropdown.Item>
                        <NavDropdown.Item onSelect={handleChange}>Knight</NavDropdown.Item>
                        <NavDropdown.Item onSelect={handleChange}>Bishop</NavDropdown.Item>
                        <NavDropdown.Item onSelect={handleChange}>Pawn</NavDropdown.Item>
                        <NavDropdown.Divider />
                        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">Separated link</NavDropdown.Item>
                        <h1>{symbol}</h1>
                    </NavDropdown>
                </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </Container>
            </Navbar>
    </div>

    </>
)
}

export default PieceNotation;
```

How to solve the error?

Answer (score 0):

the variable `symbol` is only accessible in the handleChange function, you need to set it in state so it can be updated in the jsx.

```
const [symbolValue ,setSymbolValue] = useState('K');
```

and then where you set the set the new value for `symbol` use setSymbolValue instead

```
        if(pieceValue === 'Queen'){
            setSymbolValue(Q)
        } else if(pieceValue === 'Rook') {
            setSymbolValue(R)
        } else if(pieceValue === 'Bihsop') {
            setSymbolValue(B)
        } else if(pieceValue === 'Knight') {
            setSymbolValue(K)
        } else if(pieceValue === 'Pawn') {
            setSymbolValue(P)
        }
```

and then in your Jsx, `<h1>{symbolValue}</h1>`

Comment: Yes I am able to access the `symbol` but I am not getting the value selected from dropdown to handleChange fn. How can I pass the value selected to the function `handleChange` ?

Comment: I would do a onClick listener on every item in the dropdown, calling handleChange and passing in the desired value.